# Change bar plot colour in geom_bar with ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar

I have the following in order to bar plot the data frame.

```
c1 <- c(10, 20, 40)
c2 <- c(3, 5, 7)
c3 <- c(1, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=c1+c2/2, y=c3)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=c2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FF6666"))
```

I end up having only grey bars: [Grey bars for bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQGXd.png)

I would like to change the color of the bar.
I already tried different scale_fill_manual from http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/
but still have grey bars.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you only want to change the general colors of bars, without differences between bars, write it directly in `geom_bar()`: `geom_bar(stat="identity", width=c2, color = "#FF6666")`

Comment: So this time I only have the contour of color="#FF6666", the filling stays grey.
Now if I put : `ggplot(data=df, aes(x=c1+c2/2, y=c3, fill=c3)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=c2)`
I then have a blue-ish color filled, but again, I do not get to choose manually.

Comment: `geom_bar(stat="identity", width=c2, fill = "#FF6666")` for same fill for all the bars. Use `scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FF6666"))` if you want to set color by a variable (category).

Comment: do you get a red color? Because what you just wrote is what I have put in my question and I still get grey.

I also tried `ggplot(data=df, aes(x=c1+c2/2, y=c3, fill=c3)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=c2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FF6666"))` but this gives me the error `Error : Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`

Comment: I have a red color using `ggplot(data=df, aes(x=c1+c2/2, y=c3)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=c2, fill = "#FF6666")` which is similar to `ggplot(data=df, aes(x=c1+c2/2, y=c3)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=c2, fill = "red")`

Comment: ok, this time with your last code it works. 
Thank you so much.
Can you put that as an answer maybe so I can mark as "answered"?

Comment: Already did with detailed information.

Comment: I also have issues, but with legend. It either has not corresponding colors, or the bars themselves have wrong fill color.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

If you want all the bars to get the same color (`fill`), you can easily add it inside `geom_bar`.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=c1+c2/2, y=c3)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", width=c2, fill = "#FF6666")
```

[image]

Add `fill = the_name_of_your_var` inside `aes` to change the colors depending of the variable :

```
c4 = c("A", "B", "C")
df = cbind(df, c4)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=c1+c2/2, y=c3, fill = c4)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", width=c2)
```

[image]

Use `scale_fill_manual()` if you want to manually the change of colors.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=c1+c2/2, y=c3, fill = c4)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", width=c2) + 
scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("A" = "black", "B" = "orange", "C" = "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: I like the color choice

Answer (score 1):

You could also directly assign your `x` variable to the `fill` aesthetic as a `factor` like this:

```r
c1 <- c(10, 20, 40)
c2 <- c(3, 5, 7)
c3 <- c(1, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=c1+c2/2, y=c3, fill = factor(c1+c2/2))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=c2)
```

[image]

When you know what these factors are called (this case: 11.5, 22.5, 43.5), you can simply change its colors using `scale_fill_manual` with `values` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=c1+c2/2, y=c3, fill = factor(c1+c2/2))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=c2) +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = c("11.5" = "red", "22.5" = "green", "43.5" = "blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>