# ggplot::geom_bar() - how to flip default red-blue ordering of color?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

How do I flip the default ordering of colors which ggplot picks for factor variable passed onto 'fill' aesthetic. (Here, I have a factor variable with two levels `Won` and `Lost`).

Ref image below, I'd like this 'red-family' shade to go with `Lost`; As it is, 'red' gets used for `Won` category instead of `Lost`, which in my view doesn't gel with one's common intuition of colors.

```
  ggplot(data, mapping = aes(x = Party,  y = Votes, fill = Result)) +  
     geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .6)
```

Votes scored by Political Parties in Indian State of TamilNadu:
[image: Votes scored by Political Parties in Indian State of TamilNadu]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change bar plot colour in geom\_bar with ggplot2 in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788357/change-bar-plot-colour-in-geom-bar-with-ggplot2-in-r)

Comment: This previous answers shows how to emulate `ggplot2` color scheme :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Djork for sharing the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette) which answers 'Emulate ggplot default color-palette'

I used this code-chunk to preview and select color-codes of interest, from default-palette, 
`library(scales)
 show_col(hue_pal()(4))
 hue_pal()(4)`

and later, 
`+ scale_fill_manual( values = c("#7CAE00", "#F8766D"))` 
to use the 'green' and 'red' chosen from default hue-palette.

To clarify, I found manual-colors resulting from 'green', 'red' custom-labels (as suggested in comments above) to be of very high contrast. With the hue-palette, I get nuanced color-tones.

Answer (score 0):

We can give the colors custom values.

```
ggplot(data, mapping = aes(x = Party,  y = Votes, fill = Result))
+ geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .6)
+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "yellow"))
```

Comment: It's difficult to guess w/o data.

Comment: you use `fill` to fill the bars, you use `color` to change the boundary of the bar - No need to guess here

Comment: I edited this 5 mins ago and it should work now. Doesn't it?