# ggplot bar charts are always grey

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make some stacked bar charts using ggplot2 in R, but no matter what I do my charts always end up being grey.

As a toy example, if I run this:

```
Year <- c(2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017)
Class <- c(2,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,2)
Data <- data.frame(Year,Class)

ggplot(Data, aes(Year)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Class))
```

I get the following (very grey) chart:

[image: Grey Chart]

Every ggplot tutorial I have found suggests that I should get something more colourful that looks like a stacked bar chart. Any suggestions?  I am a complete novice, so there's a fair chance it's my fault.

Comment: Both `Year` and `Class` should be factors to make this work the way you expect.

Comment: Welcome to SO! How do you want to color them? In other words, generally plots are colored with a meaning, not only for fancy purposes: which meaning do you want to give to colors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change bar plot colour in geom\_bar with ggplot2 in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788357/change-bar-plot-colour-in-geom-bar-with-ggplot2-in-r)

Comment: @Axeman or simply character vectors... ;)

Comment: Thanks!  I want the bars to be split into three differently-coloured sections showing how much of the 'count' comes from each class.  I was under the impression that that's what 'fill=Class' did?

@Axeman, could you clarify what is meant by 'factors'? I'm very new to this and still collecting terminology :)

Comment: @AmmoPT, that isn't going to be useful to OP. Clearly he already understand to map `fill` to a variable. Nowhere in that question is it explained that it should be a factor to get that specific result.

Comment: @user10310704, try e.g. `ggplot(Data, aes(factor(Year), fill = factor(Class))) +
  geom_bar()`. Read [an introductory R text](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) to understand what a factor is in R.

Comment: Thank you very much @Axeman, that works perfectly!  Cheers!!

Comment: @s_t unless you're in marketing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `stat='identity'` and a table of counts per group. Then use `position='stack'` to stack bars while preserving grouping information based on the `Class`

Default `stat='count'`, which means ggplot counts the number of times each value (here, Year), occurs, but it does not take into account any other grouping variables. `stat='identity'` means ggplot reads the values as actual bar heights.

`melt()` from `reshape2` reformats the `table()` output into long format which ggplot is able to read

```
library(ggplot2)
 library(reshape2)
 Year <- c(2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017)
 Class <- c(2,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,2)
 Data <- data.frame(Year,Class)


Data2 <- melt(table(Data))

 ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = drv))

 ggplot(Data2, aes(x=Year, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(Class)), position='stack',  stat='identity')
```